# Chrome Extension - Negative tab ID (-1) when listening for service worker network calls

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've built a chrome extension that listens for network calls across all tabs and updates its status depending on the open one.

It all works fine with regular network requests, but when I stumble upon sites making calls with a service worker, the tab ID returned by `request.tabId` is empty.

This is an issue, because I then use `chrome.tabs.get(request.tabId, function(tab)` in order to fetch the tab and do what's required by the rest of the code.

I've already tried with `chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(newTab)` as a workaround, but it returns undefined.

Is there a work-around or another solution, other than disabling the service workers in the console settings?

Comment: The observed behavior is correct and intended. Service workers don't have a tab which is why tabId is -1 and as for getCurrent() it's entirely unrelated. If you want to find the tab which is using the service worker, I don't think there's a straightforward way. You can run a content script and intercept/hook window.XMLHttpRequest and window.fetch in [page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879).

Comment: I do understand why the tab id returned would be -1, as the request is not run in a tab per se, but I believe there should still be an identifier to link the service worker that fired that request to the current tab.
Is there another way/workaround other than flooding pages with injected scripts?

Comment: @ThomasLaLicata I am facing the exact same situation today, has any reliable solution emerged yet?